# why react app cannot load local images properly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to load the local images in the react app without using `import` since if I had 100 images, that would be really not practical.

I read many posts and tried almost everything, but I cannot get this working.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ocean from './images/ocean.jpg';
```

**this works:**

```
const background = <img className='background' src={ocean} alt='ocean' />;
```

**this does not work:**

```
const background = <img className='background' src={'./images/ocean.jpg'} alt='ocean' />;
```

**also, this does not work:**

```
const background = <img className='background' src={require('./images/ocean.jpg')} alt='ocean' />;
```

Comment: Would `src={require('./images/ocean.jpg').default}` work?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros yes it did, what is the `.default` for?

Comment: You can put the images in your `public` folder and simply include them like `<img src="/images/ocean.jpg" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `src={require('./images/ocean.jpg').default}`.

If you use `require` to import your images, `require` returns an ES module instead of a simple string. It's because in [`file-loader`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/#esmodule) the `esModule` option is enabled by default.

As you don't want to use `import`, you'll need to get the `default` property of the required module.